# How can I get hokuyo published information?

Tags: ros, laser, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help. When I run hokuyo_node I suppose that it publish information about laser data, like intensity or range. I need to get that information in another node to do object detection but I dont know how to do. I tryed this:

```
ros::Subscriber hokuyoSubscriber = n_2.subscribe("scan", 1, scanValues);

void scanValues(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan laser)
{
    ROS_INFO("size[%d]: ", laser.intensities.size());
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<laser.intensities.size();i++)
    {
        intensities[i] = laser.intensities[i];
        ROS_INFO("intens[%f]: ", intensities[i]);
            
    }
}
```

But receives nothing...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10164/how-can-i-get-hokuyo-published-information?/) by [snoworld](https://answers.ros.org/users/268/snoworld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rostopic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic) and [rosnode](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosnode) tools should help you debug this.

First you can check if the Hokuyo node is publishing anything, by using 'rosnode info '. You can find the nodename by running 'rosnode list'. This should show you the topics that are published by the Hokuyo node. Check if 'scan' is one of the published topics.

Then see if there is actual data on the 'scan' topic, by running 'rosnode hz scan'. This will show you how many messages are published on the 'scan' topic.

Now see which nodes are using the 'scan' topic by running 'rostopic info scan'. You should see the Hokuyo node as a publisher, and your own node as a subscriber.  If your node is not listed as a subscriber, it can't receive any scan messages.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2